# multiple JsonArrays and JSONobject for Ajax return success?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax, servlets

I have 3 `JSONArrays` and `JSonobject` that I want to return as `success response` in `ajax`.

I have created

```
out.print(jarrayTable);
out.print(jarrayChartTotalMF);
out.print(jarrByAgeGroup);
out.print(objTotal);
```

I dont know how to get the data in `ajax - jquery`. I tried to run the program with one `JSONArray` and it perfectly works but

i dont know how to create multiple `arrays and a object and parsing` them into `jquery` variables in `return success of ajax.`

I also tried to do this, but i dont know how to parse the data in jquery

```
String json1 = new Gson().toJson(jarrayTable);
String json2 = new Gson().toJson(objTotal);
String json3 = new Gson().toJson(jarrayChartTotalMF);
String json4 = new Gson().toJson(jarrByAgeGroup);

response.setContentType("application/json");
response.setCharacterEncoding("utf-8");
String AllJson = "[" + json1 + "," + json2  + "," + json3  + "," + json4 + "]"; //Put both objects in an array of 2 elements


response.getWriter().write(AllJson);
```

---

I am currently getting this reults, how do i get the data in jquery

```
[{"ByAgeGroupSexTable":[{"BothSexes":42,"AgeGroup":"Under 1","ApprovedBy":"Geraldine Atayan","Male":25,"Female":17,"location":"Barangay 1","UploadedBy":"Shermaine Sy"},{"BothSexes":42,"AgeGroup":"Under 1","ApprovedBy":"Geraldine Atayan","Male":25,"Female":17,..."arrByAgeGroup":[{"arrByAgeGroupBothSexes":0,"arrByAgeGroupMale":25,"arrByAgeGroupFemale":17,"arrByAgeGrouplocation":"Barangay 1","arrByAgeGroupAgeGroup":"Under 1"},{"arrByAgeGroupBothSexes":0,"arrByAgeGroupMale":25,"arrByAgeGroupFemale":17,"arrByAgeGrouplocation":"Barangay...
```

this is what i get when i print it out on console by using `console.log(JSON.stringify(data));` but when i try to get the variable/data `console.log("HELLO" +print[0].ByAgeGroupSexTable[0].location);` this was the `error` `Cannot read property '0' of undefined`

This is my JS code

```
$("#archived tbody").on("click", 'input[type="button"]', (function () {

    var censusYear = $(this).closest("tr").find(".nr").text();
    alert(censusYear);
    var page = document.getElementById('page').value;
    $.ajax({
        url: "SetDataServlet",
        type: 'POST',
        dataType: "JSON",
        data: {
            censusYear: censusYear,
            page: page
        },
        success: function (data) {
            console.log(JSON.stringify(data));
             var print = JSON.stringify(data);      
             console.log("HELLO" +print[0].ByAgeGroupSexTable[0].location);
            ...some other codess

        }, error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, exception) {
            alert(XMLHttpRequest.responseText);
        }
    });
}));
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This line

```
var print = JSON.stringify(data);     //just remove JSON.stringify()
```

Converts your object to a string so you can not access it. You can easily access the object now

```
$("#archived tbody").on("click", 'input[type="button"]', (function () {
    var censusYear = $(this).closest("tr").find(".nr").text();
    alert(censusYear);
    var page = document.getElementById('page').value;
    $.ajax({
        url: "SetDataServlet",
        type: 'POST',
        dataType: "JSON",
        data: {
            censusYear: censusYear,
            page: page
        },
        success: function (data) {
            console.log(JSON.stringify(data));
            var print = data;      
            console.log("HELLO" +print[0].ByAgeGroupSexTable[0].location)

        }, error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, exception) {
            alert(XMLHttpRequest.responseText);
        }
    });
}));
```

Answer (score 3):

You could try like this. I don't know what kind of Objects have been pushed in those arraylist.

```
ArrayList<Object> allList = new ArrayList<>();

ArrayList<Object> jarrayTable = new ArrayList<Object>();
ArrayList<Object> jarrayChartTotalMF = new ArrayList<Object>();
ArrayList<Object> jarrByAgeGroup = new ArrayList<Object>();
JsonObject objTotal= new JsonObject();

allList.add(objTotal);
allList.add(jarrayTable);
allList.add(jarrayChartTotalMF);
allList.add(jarrByAgeGroup);
String allJSON = new Gson().toJson(allList);

response.setContentType("application/json");
response.setCharacterEncoding("utf-8");

se.getWriter().write(allJSON);
```

output1 :

```
 [{},[],[],[]]
```

Or

```
HashMap<String, Object> allList = new HashMap();
ArrayList<Object> jarrayTable = new ArrayList<Object>();

ArrayList<Object> jarrayChartTotalMF = new ArrayList<Object>();
ArrayList<Object> jarrByAgeGroup = new ArrayList<Object>();
JsonObject objTotal= new JsonObject();

allList.put("obj", objTotal);
allList.put("arr1",jarrayTable);
allList.put("arr2",jarrayChartTotalMF);
allList.put("arr3",jarrByAgeGroup);

String allJSON = new Gson().toJson(allList);
```

output2

```
{"obj":{},"arr2":[],"arr1":[],"arr3":[]}
```

Comment: but i also have an JSONObject

Comment: sample output: [{},[],[],[]]

Comment: Post your complete output here or create new question. What I can see the response is not completed here :(